# sum of 2 squared integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 100003,
$$
are there any integers $a$ and $b$ where this is true?
I have tried to figure out the individual digits for $a$ and $b$ to be true.
I figured out that the sum of the last one has to $13$ and as such one integer has the last digit $9$ and the other one $4$, next their nest sum is $9$ but I have not found any pattern in the second digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$100 003\equiv3\pmod4$$

For any integer $\displaystyle c\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4\implies c^2\equiv0,1 $

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This is not in base 4.

Comment: Okay now I got thank you very much.

Comment: @Andrei, Nice to hear that

Comment: I must say, I for one could use a little more explanation.

Comment: @BennettGardiner, a perfect square is always $\equiv 0, 1\pmod 4$. So, $a^2+b^2\equiv 0, 1, 2\pmod 4$, but the right hand side is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$. So the equality can not hold.